# Rails t.text_field for floats value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

a silly question

How is the way to put in a form field a float value (like a money amount)
Because if i add
`t.number_field`
I cannot get float numbers, only integers, and i want put 44.67 for example.

Comment: can you be more discriptive of where you are putting t.number_field? show the source of your migration and also your form

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really difficult to debug a verbal description of your code. Can you please edit your original question and add all the relevant code there? (don't put code in the comments as formatting is awful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the option `step` to specify the granularity in number field

```
t.number_field :number_field, :step => "0.01"
```

Above will accept numbers with two decimal points

you can also use `any` for all floats and integers

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) (number_field and number_field_tag use same options)